# No connection to default gateway

Tags: ubuntu, bonding, netplan

I freshly installed a new ubuntu server and set up netplan for 802.3ad. Now I can reach every device in my network but not the gateway and therefor the internet. The server is directly plugged into the gateway (like every other device). I don't have any iptables rules set. Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

This is my netplan config:

```
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.88.11/24
      gateway4: 192.168.88.1
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.88.4
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: fast
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
  ethernets:
    eno1: {}
    eno2: {}
  version: 2
```

Comment: What happens when you ping 192.168.88.1?

Comment: nothing, everything lost